# Why is calling .select() changing my bound data?

Tags: d3.js

In my mental model of d3, calling .select() should not change what data is bound to selections.

I've been encountering a case where calling .select() and passing it a function changes the bound data and I would appreciate an explanation of what's wrong with my mental model.

Here's a minimal case:

```
// Setup
    let body = d3.selectAll('body')
    let exampleData =
        [
            {_id:"groupOne", items:['one','two']},
            {_id:"groupTwo", items:['three','four']}
        ];
    // Add some divs
    body.selectAll('div').data(exampleData).enter().append('div');

    // Add some p children of the divs
    body.selectAll('div').selectAll('p').data((d)=>d.items).enter().append('p').text((d)=>d);

// Issue
    console.log(body.selectAll('div').data()); // data is the same as exampleData
    body.selectAll('p').select(function(){return this.parentNode}); // Select parents of all p
    console.log(body.selectAll('div').data()); // Data is now ["two","four"]
```

and here is a live version on [bl.ocks.org](https://bl.ocks.org/foobarbecue/dc3ac848f3c1a0ad9f252db8c35b43c2) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of d3: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections#select

> If the current element has associated data, this data is inherited by the returned subselection, and automatically bound to the newly selected elements.

So you select the p elements with `body.selectAll('p')` which has data `["one,"two","three","four"]`  (**this data is inherited by the returned subselection, and automatically bound to the newly selected elements.**)

Then you make a subselection with `.select(function(){return this.parentNode});`

The subselect will 'iterate' 4 times. 
Which will be the div with:
`<div><p>one</p><p>two</p></div>` for the first two 
and 
`<div><p>three</p><p>four</p></div>` for the last two.

For the first iteration; parentNode `<div><p>one</p><p>two</p></div>`, 

will get(inherit) data `"one"`.
The second iteration: data `"two"`.

In the 3rd iteration;  parentNode `<div><p>three</p><p>four</p></div>`, 

will get data `"three"`.
And four the 4th iteration: data `"four"`.

However, I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
body.selectAll('p').select(this.parentNode); // Select parents of all p
console.log(body.selectAll('div').data()); // Data is now the same as exampleData
```

(Without the return statement)

Comment: Thanks -- failure to RTFM on my part here -- I'm surprised to learn that .select modifies the state -- somehow I thought there was no change until the .data() call. However, I don't get why you're saying I should change my "select parents" function to a statement. I tried it and I just end up with a null selection. The docs for select say it takes a selector or a function... I can't find anything in there about passing an element to it directly. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, is there any way I can select the parents without modifying their data content?

Comment: @foobarbecue Hey! sorry for the late reply (i went to sleep ;P) I don't know how you ended up getting null with my suggestion but here's a fiddle of what I meant. https://jsfiddle.net/fchr2f3o/

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. I tried your fiddle and added console.log() around the select parentNode line. As I expected, the version without the "return" in it is useless because the selection it returns is an array of 4 null. No sense in passing a statement to select() -- it requires a function.